# Cannot build Flann

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build the newest groovy on my debian testing distro, following the wiki instructions under the ubuntu source pa. ( I got wstool, rospkg and rosdep via Pip btw. not from the ubuntu repos)

I can init my catkinworkspace (even desktop-full), dependencies also complete with a success state.

However when invoking: $ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install

It fails on building flann (and we do kinda need it). the relevant output from the console can be found at the bottom of the message (I can't post my pastebin link? :S)

Unfortunately nothing really useful to me, maybe not all errors are displayed? Anyone got thoughts on it?

Cheers,
Riemer van der Zee

---

```
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libflann_cpp_s.a
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libflann_cpp-gd.so
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libflann_cpp_s-gd.a
[ 50%] Built target flann_cpp_s
[ 50%] Built target flann_cpp_s-gd
[ 62%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/cpp/CMakeFiles/flann_cuda_s.dir/flann/algorithms/./flann_cuda_s_generated_kdtree_cuda_3d_index.cu.o
Scanning dependencies of target flann_cuda-gd
[ 75%] Building CXX object src/cpp/CMakeFiles/flann_cuda-gd.dir/flann/flann_cpp.cpp.o
[ 75%] Built target flann_cpp-gd
Scanning dependencies of target flann_cuda_s-gd
No such file or directory
[ 87%] CMake Error at flann_cuda_s_generated_kdtree_cuda_3d_index.cu.o.cmake:198 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/riemer/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/flann/src/cpp/CMakeFiles/flann_cuda_s.dir/flann/algorithms/./flann_cuda_s_generated_kdtree_cuda_3d_index.cu.o
 
 
make[2]: *** [src/cpp/CMakeFiles/flann_cuda_s.dir/flann/algorithms/./flann_cuda_s_generated_kdtree_cuda_3d_index.cu.o] Fout 1
make[1]: *** [src/cpp/CMakeFiles/flann_cuda_s.dir/all] Fout 2
make[1]: *** Wachten op onvoltooide taken...
Building CXX object src/cpp/CMakeFiles/flann_cuda_s-gd.dir/flann/flann_cpp.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libflann_cuda_s-gd.a
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libflann_cuda-gd.so
[ 87%] Built target flann_cuda_s-gd
[ 87%] Built target flann_cuda-gd
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libflann_s.a
[ 87%] Built target flann_s
make: *** [all] Fout 2
 
<== Failed to process package 'flann':
  Command '/home/riemer/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4' returned non-zero exit status 2
 
Reproduce this error by running:
==> /home/riemer/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54725/cannot-build-flann/) by [Riemer van der Zee](https://answers.ros.org/users/4165/riemer-van-der-zee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"No such file or directory" seems to cause this, maybe a directory is not created as it should.

But since other users have build groovy from source without running into that error, the origin of the problem is probably either something different about your build environment or that you use a broken version of flann that few other people tried.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3